# Translating nested query from GraphQL to Graphene not working

Tags: python-3.x, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

So I have a GraphQL API which I wrote a query to and it works and sent me back data in GraphiQL.

```
query dishes {
  dishes {
    name
    recipeNote
    description
  }
}
```

This is my Graphene translation of what I have

```py
class Dish(ObjectType):
    name = String()
    recipeNote = String()
    description = String()
class Query(ObjectType):
    first = Field(Dish)

    def resolve_first(parent, info):
        return parent
query_string = "{ first { dishes { name recipeNote description } } }"

result = schema.execute(
        query_string)
print(result)
print(result.data)
```

However this gives me an error `{'errors': [{'message': 'Cannot query field "dishes" on type "Dish".', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column': 11}]}]}`

Comment: Your graphene translation as well as the query is not correct. I assume you are trying to fetch all the dishes. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from graphene import List, ObjectType, String

class Dish(ObjectType):
    name = String()
    recipeNote = String()
    description = String()


class Query(ObjectType):
    dishes = List(Dish)

    def resolve_dishes(parent, info):
        return [Dish(name='', recipeNote='', description=''), ...]

query_string = "query dishes {
  dishes {
    name
    recipeNote
    description
  }
}"

result = schema.execute(
        query_string)
print(result)
print(result.data)
```